# What are JavaScript Objects and Properties?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Can anyone explain objects and properties to me in Javascript in layman's terms? The Javascript MDN documentation is confusing me.

I am trying to solve a problem in a Javascript tutorial about objects and properties The question is below and my attempt at the code, I think I followed the MDN as far as I can grasp it. Any help would be appreciated!

Question: Add the value of the property argument as a key on the object argument.
The value of the new property should be set to null.
Return object after adding the new property.

Input Example:

```
{}, 'hello'
{ x: 5 }, 'y'
```

Output Example:

```
{ hello: null }
{ x: 5, y: null }
```

note: the property name is NOT 'property'.  The name is the value of the argument called property (a string).

My code: 
//NOTE: the function addProperty(object, property) was already in the console and I have to write the solution inside of it.

```
function addProperty(object, property) {
  // code here
  let result = addProperty({x: 5}, 'y');
  obj[property] = null;
  return obj;
}

addProperty(x, 'y');
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: If any of the answers below met your needs, please be sure to reward them with a +1, and the best should get an acceptance; this keeps people interested in helping answer questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Layman's explanation:**

An object is a collection of properties.  You can give a name to the object to keep things organized.  For example, lets create a person object.

`var person = {};`

The object has no properties right now.  To further describe the person we can add properties to the object.

```
person.Name = 'Zim';
person.Age = 29;
person.Gender = 'Male';
person.Weight = 80;
```

Now this object has some properties to help describe it.  A different way to write the same thing:

`var person = { Name: 'Zim', Age: 29, Gender: 'Male', Weight: 80 };`

If we had to create a program that displays a list of people, storing all of our information inside objects would help keep things organized.

Object properties are sometimes referred to as keys.

---

**Adding properties to objects:**

You can add a property to an object using brackets, just like you had in your `addProperty` function.  If you just need it to add a property, set that property to null and return the result it would look something like this:

```
function addProperty(object, property) {
  // code here
  object[property] = null;
  return object;
}
```

This would let us create a properies on our object from above by calling

```
addProperty(person, 'Occupation');
addProperty(person, 'Income');
addProperty(person, 'Height');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're over-thinking it.

First the question:

> Add the value of the **property argument** as a **key** on the **object
>   argument**. The **value** of the new property should be set to null. Return
>   object after adding the new property.

*emphasis added*

So, property will be the KEY (of a [key/value pair](http://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/definition/key-value-pair)), and the VALUE will be null of **object**, which we are also passing in as an argument.

One way to interrogate key/value pairs on a javascript object is through the square-brackets [].  So, if you have a key/value pair: { foo: "bar" }, you can get "bar" by: object['foo'].  You can also create new key/value pairs like this, so your function can look like:

```
function addProperty(object, property) {
    object[property] = null;
    return object;
}

var obj = {};

obj = addProperty(obj, "hello");

console.log(obj);
console.log(addProperty({x: 5}, 'y'));
```

What our function is doing is taking the object passed into it (as an argument), creating a new KEY with our property argument, and setting its VALUE to null, and simply returning the object.

***Side note -**

Be careful, the code you have posted will create an endless recursive loop, as you keep calling the same function with no way to break out of it.

Answer (score 2):

This particular example is simple:

```
var one={};
var two={x:5};
function addProperty(object property){
  obj[property]=null;
  return obj;
}

addProperty(one, 'hello'); 
addProperty(two, 'y');
```

Objects in javascript are really flexible, their properties can be added or removed, even when set from the very beginning.

If you take:

```
var x={};
```

**x** will be an object with nothing in it, but if instead of that you write:

```
var x={
  inner:'b'
};
```

**x** will be an object with a property called **inner** which value is 'b', now, if we want to access that property we could do something like this:

```
var valueOfInner=x.inner;
```

or

```
var valueOfInner=x['inner'];
```

The same if we want to change the value of that property:

```
x.inner=8;
```

or

```
x['inner']=8;
```

Now, you'll notice that when we use x.['inner'], we could very well use instead:

```
var propertyName='inner';
x[propertyName]=8;
```

So you can access and modify a property of an object without actually knowing exactly which property you're manipulating.

Finally, if you're (willing or by accident) trying to set the value of a property that doesn't exists, the property will be automatically be created, for example:

```
x['blah']=456;
```

Will create the property **blah** even when it wasn't defined at first.

Edit: yes, you can define the object and define its properties later:

```
var x={};
//more code or something
x['y']=777;//now x has a y property with the value 777
```

Comment: So if I were to create an Object, the x would be the descriptor? Like say, I created an object but I don't know yet what properties I want to give the object, I can leave them blank and then  add the descriptor and value later?

Answer (score 0):

a property is a key:

```
let obj = {
    name: 'Jordan',
    age: 15
}
```

obj.name is a property, same goes for obj.age.