# Incorrectly returning an Object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a following function that looks like this:

```
    function addProperty(object, property) {

}
```

I have to add the value of the property argument as a key to the object argument. The value of the new property must be set to null. After that, i will return the object with the newly added property to it. The expected input is something like this: `{ x: 5 }, 'y'` with the object to the left and property on the right. The expected output is this: `{ x: 5, y: null }`.

This is what i have so far:

```
function addProperty(object, property) {
   object = { object, [property]: null};
  return object;
}

addProperty({x:5}, 'y');
```

This is the output i get: `{ object: { x: 5 }, y: null }`. What am i doing wrong here? how do i get rid of what looks like an object property at the beginning of the output and leave the object itself and the property??.

Comment: Note that by doing this, it will edit `object` outside the scope of your function. That means that even if you don't return `object`, the one you passed as an argument will be modified. Example: `addProperty(someObject, 'y')` will add `y: null` to the already existing object `someObject`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are JavaScript Objects and Properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338748/what-are-javascript-objects-and-properties)

Comment: This code has been featured in four or five questions during the last week.  Homework?

Comment: My apologies James, i thought  i used the search features correctly. My original post had a warning that if the question was found to be a duplicate, i would remove it. Unfortunately, that statement was edited by Jordumus. Perhaps the statement was inadequate for stack. The code originates from Lambda's School which is similar to a boot-camp.  Please note that I asked the community if they knew what i was doing wrong, in which Ori answered beautifully. I hope my question is not being confused with a "Homework ask and answer question".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create a new object based on the original, with the new property:

```js
function addProperty(object, property) {
   return Object.assign({}, object, { [property]: null });
}

console.log(addProperty({x:5}, 'y'));
```

Or use the [Object Rest/Spread proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) (requires Babel and the [transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)):

```js
function addProperty(object, property) {
  return { ...object, [property]: null };
}

console.log(addProperty({x:5}, 'y'));
```

**What's wrong with your code:**

When you write `{ object }`, you are using [ES6 Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to create a new object literal, that has the property "object", with the old object's value. Effectively you are writing:

```
object = { object: object }
```

```js
function addProperty(object, property) {
  object = { // assign a new object literal to the object variable
    object, // add a new property by name of "object" with the contents of the original object
    [property]: null
  };
  return object;
}

console.log(addProperty({x:5}, 'y'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Set object property like this :

```
function addProperty(object, property) {
  object[property] =  null;
  return object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the property of object this way

```js
function addProperty(object, property) {
   object[property] = null
  return object;
}
console.log(addProperty({x:5}, 'y'));
```

In`ES6`,The `Object.defineProperty()` method defines a new property directly on an object, or modifies an existing property on an object, and returns the object.

```js
function addProperty(object, property) {
Object.defineProperty(object, property, {
 value: null,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
  return object;
}
var o = {x:5};
console.log(addProperty(o, 'y'));
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)